# How to access a flat list and perform math functions on the second value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is an assignment for school. I have a text file which contains the following abbreviated list with each entry on a single line. The first entry is the date and the second entry after the pip is the value for stock market close, there are approximately 365 entries in the file.

```
8/28/2018|26064.01953
8/29/2018|26124.57031
8/30/2018|25986.91992
```

Using the following code I have split the data into a list of lists with the date and value separated.

```
import os
import math
import statistics
def main ():
    infile = open('DJI.txt', 'r')
    values = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    values=values.split("\n")
    values=[value.split("|") for value in values]
    print(values)
    avg = sum([float(l[1]) for l in values])/len(values)
main()
```

This gives the following output

```
[['8/28/2018', '26064.01953'], ['8/29/2018', '26124.57031'], ['8/30/2018', '25986.91992'],
```

the Avg line gives the following error: IndexError: list index out of range, however when I switch the 1 to 0  it givers a different error which says could not convert string to float for 8/28/2018

My task is to create a program which calculates 
Average close value for the entire year.
Average close value per month
Highest close value and the date in which that happened. 
Lowest close value and the date of which that happened. 
Sort prices lowest to highest and write the sorted list to a new text file called DJI_Sorted.

I am having trouble with how to access the second value in the list of lists to perform the statistics on the file. I am also unsure how I would write a code which sorts the list from lowest to highest as well as the average close for each month, rather than on the entire file.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the text file?

Comment: Is there a way to attach the file or did you just mean post the data?

Comment: Yes, You can upload your text file

Comment: Your text file probably is inconsistent. You should share the text file for use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: text file: https://gofile.io/?c=wpjF0n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an empty line at the very end. 
Modify the line computing average to this

```py
avg = sum([float(x[1]) for x in values if len(x) > 1])/len(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    infile = open('DJI.txt', 'r')
    values = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    values = values.split("\n")
    values = [value.split("|") for value in values if len(value.split("|")) > 1]
    print(values)
    avg = sum([float(l[1]) for l in values]) / len(values)
    print("-------avg--------", avg)
main()
```